# Prove that a function is differentiable everywhere using the limit definition of a derivative

Tags: derivatives

I have thw function $$f(x) = (e^x+x^4)\cos(-2x) $$ which is defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

How do I prove it's differentiable for all x using the limit definition? I'm neither getting conclusive results with $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$ nor with $$\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0} $$ when I plug in the function for $f(x)$ and try to rearrange anf simplify it.

What am I missing?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Edit: Is the trick here to Show that all 4 'partial' functions are differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, thus making the composition of them differentiable in  $\mathbb{R}$ as well?

Comment: @MikkoPesonen How do you get Taylor series if you don't even know whether the function is differentiable or not.

Comment: @MikkoPesonen This problem was asked before the introduction of taylor series, so it must be solveable without it.

Comment: The rules of differentiation exist for very good reasons. *Why* do you want to use the limit to prove the function is differentiable?

Comment: You should have a review of the derivation of $(fg)'=f'g+fg'$

Comment: @Fan I know how to differentiate it, but I have to prove that it's differentiable at all.

Comment: @Skydiver I mean the derivation of the product rule is exactly the same how you do here

Comment: When you're trying to prove that the limit exists, you should not use any techniques involving derivatives as their validity ASSUMES that limit exists, unless you're doing proof by contradiction (which is hard to do). Now using fundamental principles (actually seeing the limit exists) it's a different story. :-)

Answer (score 2):

HINT: we have $$\frac{f(x)-f(x_o)}{x-x_o}=\frac{(e^x+x^4)\cos(-2x)-(e^{x_0}+x_0^4)\cos(-2x_0)}{x-x_0}$$ and use $$\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

I think this takes multiple applications of the product trick:  If you need to work with $ab-cd$, it sometimes helps to transition from one product to the other one factor at a time:

$$ab - cd = ab -cb + cb -cd = (a-c)b + c(b-d).$$

You can multiply your function out and treat each sum separately.  I'll do the first:

$$\frac{e^{x+h}\cos(-2(x+h)) - e^x\cos(-2x)}{h} $$

$$= \frac{e^{x+h}\cos(-2(x+h)) -e^{x}\cos(-2(x+h)) + e^{x}\cos(-2(x+h)-e^x\cos(-2x) }{h}$$

$$= \frac{\cos(-2(x+h))(e^{x+h}-e^x)}{h} + \frac{e^x(\cos(-2(x+h))-\cos(-2x))}{h}$$

You get two more, similar terms for the $x^4$ part.  When you take the limit, everything works out swell.